# Where does the FAT region of FAT16 begin?

Tags: fat16

I'm writing a C program that reads FAT16 file images.  I have a variable that stores the location of the beginning of the FAT.  What value should I put there?

I was able to find the beginning of the Reserved Region, and have determined:
- BytesPerSec = read( image, 11, 2 )
- SectorCount16 = read( image, 19, 2 )
- etc

Is there any way to determine the offset of the FAT from the boot partition block, or the boot sector?

Does it begin right after the boot sector?
Does this mean LAST_BYTE( boot_sector ) +1 is the first byte of the FAT?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: @KenWhite and wouldn't it fit under Software Algorithms?

Comment: No, physical structure on disk does not mean it's related to an algorithm. Your edit makes the question suitable for here, though. :-)